# svg width in morphing animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hell0, I can't get my svg to take the whole width of the screen!
it doesn't matter if they are distorted or not because the idea of this use is a kind of morphing to change the background color of my page

here is my css:

```
.container {
height: 5000px; /* hauteur de la page */
}
.img {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
object-fit: fill;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0; 
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
opacity: 0;
}
.img.transition {
transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
}
.img.active {
opacity: 1;
}
```

the complete code is here : [codepen](https://codepen.io/jipe974/pen/NWLWBVZ)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think adding `viewBox` parameter to your svg's might help. The 3th and 4th number give it a relative width and height. In the example below, giving it 100% w x h.

Check this out for more info -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Also you cannot use the same CSS properties for HTML nodes, also for SVG. Properties like `object-fit`, `margin`, `position`,etc... wil not work on SVG elements, unfortunately.

More info on that here -> https://css-tricks.com/svg-properties-and-css/

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>
```